# Generate 3 dimensional random vectors

Tags: vector, random

How can one generate a random vector $v=[v_1, v_2, v_3]^T$ satisfying $\sqrt{v_1v_1^* + v_2 v_2^* + v_3 v_3^*} = 1$, where $T$ and $*$ denote the transpose and complex-conjugate, respectively?

Comment: Try `lst=Normalize /@ RandomReal[{}, {n, 3}]` where instead of `n` you should put the desired number of vectors. By evaluation `lst /. {x_, y_, z_} -> x^2 + y^2 + z^2` you can make sure that they all have a unit length.

Comment: For the complex vectors make the same with `RandomComplex` and use `lst /. {x_, y_, z_} -> 
   x*Conjugate[x] + y*Conjugate[y] + z*Conjugate[z] // Chop` for the check.

Comment: Note that there are no "row vectors" or "column vectors" in Mathematica. Vectors are 1-index tensors and cannot be transposed.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch The distribution you get this way will not be uniform on the sphere.

Comment: @Szabolcs The OP did not ask for the uniform distribution, but only for a list of random vectors.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch The big question: what does "random _object_ satisfying _criterion_" mean? I maintain that without additional information, the only reasonable interpretation is that the distribution must be uniform. If any distribution would be acceptable, then I propose assigning probability 1 to the vector `{1,0,0}` and zero to everything else. You might that that that is not random, but why? It is a valid distribution. Then I would ask you to define what you mean by "random".

Comment: I do agree that many people who ask such question tend to forget about this subtle, but very important point. Sometimes this even leads to flawed studies/conclusions. The question _should_ specify the distribution, and not just say "random". It's useful to also mention Bertrand's paradox here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

Comment: @Szabolcs Maybe you are right. I do not argue against it, the more that I like your solution. Maybe OP, indeed, did not think about such subtleties, as you proposed. Also maybe the OP aim was much simpler than the one you assumed, and a nonuniform set of vectors is OK for him. I propose that we leave the decision for OP.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch my solution is almost as simple as yours, but gives a uniform distribution on the sphere.  There is no need to compromise uniformity to obtain simplicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very simple 1-liner giving a list of `n` such random vectors

```
sphericalrandom[n_] := Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, 3}]
```

Note that these are uniformly distributed on the sphere, since the multivariate normal distribution is invariant under rotation (consider the covariance matrix, `R.I.Transpose[R] = I`)

We can easily verify that the requirement is met

```
sphericalrandom[6]
(* {{-0.277119, -0.913442, -0.298042}, {0.784793, 
  0.124294, -0.607166}, {0.0794014, -0.138744, 0.98714}, {0.477633, 
  0.578417, -0.661287}, {0.182014, -0.443811, 
  0.877441}, {-0.967141, -0.236544, 0.0931965}} *)

# . # & /@ %
(* {1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.} *)
```

The question seems to request complex numbers subject to the same criteria.  This is very easily done

```
sphericalrandomcomplex[n_] := 
 Normalize /@ (RandomVariate[
     NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, 3, 2}] . {1, I})
```

Again, the normalisation checks

```
sphericalrandomcomplex[6]
(* {{0.0291155 + 0.299873 I, 0.118097 + 0.105762 I, 
  0.872673 + 0.350054 I}, {-0.476609 - 0.271261 I, 
  0.762756 + 0.326494 I, 
  0.0928805 - 0.0473263 I}, {0.482045 + 0.36627 I, -0.627184 - 
   0.11854 I, 
  0.183277 + 0.438722 I}, {-0.445669 - 0.472578 I, -0.0542457 + 
   0.260653 I, 0.129732 + 0.700241 I}, {0.398994 + 0.191309 I, 
  0.147118 - 0.353526 I, -0.455474 - 0.670913 I}, {-0.157891 + 
   0.0766977 I, 0.66208 + 0.28717 I, -0.261425 + 0.616465 I}} *)

# . Conjugate[#] & /@ %
(* {1. + 0. I, 1. + 0. I, 1. + 0. I, 1. + 0. I, 1. + 0. I, 
 1. + 0. I} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. How can we restrict the elements of these vectors to be positive? That is, in my question, if $v_i \ge 0$

Comment: You can simply take the absolute value of each component, using `Abs/@v`

Answer (score 7):

Generate a single such vector:

```
Complex @@@ Partition[RandomPoint@Sphere[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}], 2]
```

Generate `n` of them with good performance:

```
n = 100;

#1 + I #2 & @@ Transpose[
  ArrayReshape[RandomPoint[Sphere[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}], n], {n, 3, 2}],
  {2, 3, 1}
]
```

This method will sample uniformly from the 3-dimensional complex sphere.

---

At this point, it is appropriate to discuss why one of the suggestions in the comments will not work. The suggestion is the following for reals:

```
lst=Normalize /@ RandomReal[{}, {n, 3}]
```

or the same with `RandomComplex` for complexes.

This will not sample uniformly from the sphere. It sampled from the unit cube, then normalized each element. That leads to a biased distribution, first, because we are restricted to the first octant. This fault is easily fixed by extending to all octants:

```
lst = Normalize /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10000, 3}];
```

However, the sampling is still not uniform, as vectors in the direction of the cube edges will appear more frequently. This is plainly visible in a plot:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Point[lst]}]
```

[image]

This can be saved by restricting the sampling to the unit ball before normalizing each vector:

```
n = 100;
eps = 0.001;
result = Normalize /@ Select[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3}], eps < Norm[#] <= 1 &];
```

`eps` here is an abirtrary small number that helps avoid numerical imprecision for points very close to the origin. Extension to complexes is possible with `RandomComplex[{-1-I, 1+I}, ...]`.

However, this method does not generate `n` points, but fewer.

```
Length[result]
(* 53 *)
```

One needs to do a bit more work to get precisely `n` points. This is why I chose to use `RandomPoint` for my answer.

**Update:** See [@mikado's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/250080/12) which starts with the normal distribution (which is isotropic) instead of uniform distribution in a cube, and thus avoids the need for the `Select` above, and makes it easy to generate precisely the desired number of points.